# "Of all the students, none [is/are] as attentive as he is"? "she asks all 5 of them, none [knows/know] the answer"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

In the sentence "I asked all 5 of them, none [knows/know] the answer", should I use the plural or singular verb?

For reference, I found this website that explains it: https://editorsmanual.com/articles/none-is-or-are/

Unfortunately, all examples given were "none of", and not one of them was about the actual "none".

I also tried to ask on Quora, but my question kept being modified for some reason, so I'm asking for help.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: I'm not sure that works well as a general rule, because "none" is not equivalent to "no one". (For example: "None" is an acceptable answer to "How much coffee have you drunk?", but "No one" is not.)

Comment: If I try to sub it with "no one", the answer would be singular, but this conflicts a question I've asked long ago: ( https://www.quora.com/Are-both-singular-and-plural-verbs-correct-in-There-used-to-be-cats-in-the-house-but-now-there-arent-isnt-ANY-left-and-there-used-to-be-cats-in-the-house-but-now-there-are-is-NONE-left ) All the answers pointed out how "none is" is wrong...

Comment: You should substitute "none" with "not any" then it is clear.